# Ограничение перемещения изображения в Scatter

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Имеется вот такой кусок кода в kv-файле:

```
Scatter:
    do_rotation:False
    scale_min:1
    scale_max:4.
    AsyncImage:
        size:root.size
        pos:root.pos
        id:now_image
        mipmap:False
        nocache:False
        source:''
```

В какую сторону копать чтобы ограничить перемещение изображения.
Сейчас я хватаю пальцем и могу перемещать сколько угодно лишь бы была возможность схватить. Хочеться чтобы перемещалось в определенной рамке. На сайте kivy есть упоминание bbox Scatter'a, но как его использовать... Не понял.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, как-то можно все это реализовать, но в чужом коде разбираться сложнее, чем сделать свой велосипед, а вопрос, все же, не дает покоя... И, благо, сделать свой виджет или лейаут средства киви позволяют.

В итоге родилось что-то, что может увеличивать картинку, но с некоторыми нюансами:
1)Экран должен быть ориетирован, как "портрет" - высота экрана должна быть больше высоты картинки, что удовлетворяется экраном сматфона(для чего собственно это и делалось);
2)Иногда некоторые картинки не увеличиваются на полную высоту экрана(ну там не полная высота, а высота виджета, в котором находиться картинка), а иногда все изображение располагается на полную высоту виджета.

вот код, который вышел в итоге:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollImage>:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint:(None,None)
        width:root.my_width*2
        height:root.my_height*0.9
        pos:(0,root.my_height*0.1)
        AsyncImage:
            id:img
            source:'test_pic.jpg'
            size_hint:(None,1)
            width:root.my_width
            pos:(0,0)

<Main>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    ScrollImage:
        id:content
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint:(None,None)
        width:root.my_width
        height:root.my_height*0.1
        pos:(0,0)
        Button:
            text:'reset'
            on_press:content.my_reset()
        Button:
            text:'2x'
            on_press:content.tooiks()
''')


class ScrollImage(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.my_width=Window.width
        self.my_height=Window.height
        self.default_pos=(0,0)
        self.default_width=self.my_width
        self.myscroll=False
        self.clock_flag=False
        self.trigger_flag=True
        self.clock=Clock.schedule_once(self.change_flag,0.3)
        self.clock.cancel()
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def my_reset(self):#возващает изображение в изначальные параметры
        if self.myscroll:
            self.ids.img.size_hint=(None,1)
            self.ids.img.width=self.default_width
            self.ids.img.pos=self.default_pos
            self.myscroll=False

    def tooiks(self):#дурацкое название функции, ничего не говорит, но... Эта функция увеличивает изображение до высоты экрана и разрешает перемещать по оси "х"
        if self.myscroll==False:
            self.ids.img.width=self.my_height*0.9*self.ids.img.image_ratio
            self.myscroll=True

    def on_touch_down(self,touch):#не понял как использовать даблтач и написал свой
        if self.clock_flag==False:
            self.clock_flag=True
            self.clock()
            return
        if self.clock_flag:
            self.mytrigger()
            self.clock_flag=False
            self.clock.cancel()
            return

    def change_flag(self,dt):#этот флаг нужен для фиксирования второго касания
        self.clock_flag=False

    def mytrigger(self):#то увеличивает изображение, то уменьшает
        if self.trigger_flag==True:
            self.tooiks()
            self.trigger_flag=False
            return
        else:
            self.my_reset()
            self.trigger_flag=True
            return

    def on_touch_move(self,touch):#катает изображение по оси "х"
        if self.myscroll:
            if self.ids.img.x>=-(self.ids.img.width-self.my_width) and self.ids.img.x<=0:
                self.ids.img.x+=touch.dx
                if self.ids.img.x<-(self.ids.img.width-self.my_width):
                    self.ids.img.x=-(self.ids.img.width-self.my_width)
                if self.ids.img.x>0:
                    self.ids.img.x=0

class Main(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.my_width=Window.width
        self.my_height=Window.height
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


if __name__=="__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Однако мне пришлось встроить его в свое приложение, чтобы показать результат на разных картинках.

Вот первый один случай:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как оно выглядит после увеличения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот другой второй случай:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И каким оно становиться после увеличения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работает.

Можно будет поиграться еще со RelativeLayout, с помощью которого все тот же Scatter и сделан, и сделать что-то еще подобное. Но это в будущем.